# Why is XKeysymToKeycode() making all of my keys lowercase?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm currently having a problem with Xlib where whenever I call `XKeysymToKeycode()` and pass in an uppercase `KeySym`, it returns a lowercase `KeyCode`. Google doesn't really seem to have an answer to this question, or too much documentation at all on the functions I'm using, for that matter.

Here's the code I am using:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>

int main(void) {
    Display *display;
    char *ptr;
    char c[2] = {0, 0};
    KeySym ksym;
    KeyCode kcode;

    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    ptr = "Test";

    while (*ptr) {
        c[0] = *ptr;
        ksym = XStringToKeysym(c);
        printf("Before XKeysymToKeycode(): %s\n", XKeysymToString(ksym));
        kcode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, ksym);
        printf("Key code after XKeysymToKeycode(): %s\n", XKeysymToString(XKeycodeToKeysym(display, kcode, 0)));
        ptr++;
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled with `gcc -o sendkeys sendkeys_min.c -lX11 -lXtst -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi` (Assuming it has been saved as `sendkeys_min.c`.)

The current output is the following:

```
Before XKeysymToKeycode(): T
Key code after XKeysymToKeycode(): t
Before XKeysymToKeycode(): e
Key code after XKeysymToKeycode(): e
Before XKeysymToKeycode(): s
Key code after XKeysymToKeycode(): s
Before XKeysymToKeycode(): t
Key code after XKeysymToKeycode(): t
```

The expected output, is, of course, that the first T in "Test" is still uppercase after being ran through `XKeysymToKeycode()`. (Note that this is not my actual program, but a simplified version for posting here. In the actual program, I am sending key events with the resulting keycode, and the keys sent still have the problem exhibited here (They all become lowercase))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KeySyms` and `KeyCodes` are semantically different, and there is not a 1-1 relationship between them.

- A `KeyCode` is an arbitrary small integer representing a key on the keyboard. (Not a character. A key.) Xlib requires that key codes be in the range `[8, 255]`, but fortunately most keyboards have only a bit more than 100 keys.
- A `KeySym` is a representation of some actual character associated with a key. There will almost always be several of these: lower- and upper-case letters correspond to the same key on most terminal layouts.

So there is no such thing as an "upper-case" or "lower-case" `KeyCode`. When you get the `KeyCode` corresponding to a Keysym, you are actually losing information.

In Xlib, a given key has at least four corresponding `KeySyms` (lower-case, upper-case, alternate lower-case, alternate upper-case), although some might be unassigned. When you ask for the `KeySym` corresponding to a `KeyCode`, you need to supply an index; index 0 (as in your code) will get the unshifted unmodified character.

For a given keypress, the translation to a KeySym will take into account the state of the modifier keys. There are eight of these, including the `Shift` and `Lock` modifiers. Ignoring `Lock`, which complicates the situation, the shift modifier key would normally turn lower-case letters into their upper-case equivalents (for alphabetic keys).

Keyboard handling is much more complicated than that brief summary, but it's a start.

For your task, you probably should take a look at `XkbKeysymToModifiers`.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense to me... But the issue is, in the original program, I'm never translating that KeyCode back to a KeySym. I'm using it to send a key event, and when I send that key event, the key is sent as lowercase. I would assume, then, that I would have to send a key event of pressing shift before I press the key that I want to be uppercase?

Comment: @AppleDash: If you are fabricating key press events, you need (at least) to set the `state` member of the event structure (which includes a bitmask for modifier keys). Most apps don't care about modifier key presses and releases; I honestly don't know how the internals of X handles those; so my guess is that setting the state is sufficient but I have no real experience to base that on.